# Any negative side effects to disabling caching in a Liferay production environment?

Tags: caching, properties, liferay-6, production-environment

Our production Liferay instance absolutely *refuses* to deploy my latest theme. Something is preventing it from displaying my latest CSS changes. Unfortunately, there are NO log errors and no Firebug Console errors, so it's been a real headache to diagnose. I just get a really ugly plain page with links and no styles applied.
I have tried everything I can think of to fix this.

- Undeploy/redeploy theme
- restart the Glassfish container
- use Liferay Server Administration page to "Clear content cached across this JVM", "Clear database cache", "Verify Database plugins", etc.
- undeploy, restart, redeploy
- undeploy, delete leftover files/folders pertaining to the theme in 'applications' folder, restart container, redeploy
- clear my browser cache
- try a different browser
- many more combinations of the above. You get the idea.

Last night I reached the boiling point because my theme deployed and displayed in our test environments without issue, but didn't work in production. The only thing that was different is that I wasn't using

```
include-and-override=portal-developer.properties
```

in my portal-ext.properties file.
I took a gamble and added this line to my production portal-ext.properties and restarted the production server. My theme now displays without a problem.

The file portal-developer.properties only appears to contain the following properties:

```
theme.css.fast.load=false
theme.images.fast.load=false

javascript.fast.load=true
javascript.log.enabled=false

layout.template.cache.enabled=false

browser.launcher.url=

combo.check.timestamp=true

freemarker.engine.cache.storage=soft:1
freemarker.engine.modification.check.interval=0

openoffice.cache.enabled=false

velocity.engine.resource.manager.cache.enabled=false

com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.cache.CacheFilter=false
com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.etag.ETagFilter=false
com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.header.HeaderFilter=false
com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.themepreview.ThemePreviewFilter=true
```

So, finally, my question is, am I merely trading a slight performance boost for a massively easier deployment experience?

Or are there more serious concerns to loading this file in a production environment?

Thanks in advance for the input!

Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll get a really bad performance with that `portal-ext.properties`. That configuration is only intended to be used in development environments.

If you delete the `css/.sass_cache` directory on your deployed theme you'll see your css changes and you'll be able to use a different `portal-ext.properties` on production environment.

http://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-26939

Regards

Comment: Thank you for the response, especially the link. That really helped to clear up my confusion around the original problem.